# Windows form with list views, dragging and dropping, need source list view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

Using VS 2008 I have a windows form with 2 ListViews (we will call them ListView1 and ListView2).  ListView1 is populated with FileNames from a directory.  When an item is dragged from ListView1 to ListView2 I have some code that is executed.  When I dragDrop from ListView2 to ListView1 some code executes.  What I want to do is NOT execute the code if you dragdrop from ListView2 onto itself

Here is the dragDrop Method which is invoked after a drop:

`private void view_DragDrop(object dropTarget, DragEventArgs e)`

I have tried a few items such as below:

`ListView data = (ListView)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.ListView")`

This returns null what I wanted to do with the above is see if data = dropTarget, do not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create you a variable, in the scope of your form

```
object dfrom;
//your methods ect
    private void view_ItemDrag(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ItemDragEventArgs e)
    //your code to drag items
    dfrom = sender
}
private void view_DragDrop(object dropTarget, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (dfrom == sender){return;}//this will protect both list boxes (assuming you can drag from both).
    //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably verify the source of the event and make sure the target is not the same by using the `OriginalSource` attribute.

So in your `DragDrop` event on your `ListView2`, I'd do something like this:

```
private void view_DragDrop(object dropTarget, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource == ListView2)
       return;

    //Rest of the code here
}
```

This will prevent any items that got Dragged from `ListView2` to trigger your code execution in `ListView2`.

[DragEventArgs Class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.drageventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Message for "E.OriginalSource" .'System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'OriginalSource' and no extension method 'OriginalSource' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)